# How to bind to a float2

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, wpf-controls

I tried these:

```
<effects:HighPass InputSize="{Binding Width},{Binding Height}"/>

<effects:HighPass InputSize="{Binding Width} {Binding Height}"/>

<effects:HighPass InputSize="{Binding Width Height}"/>
```

but none of them work.

However if I directly pass in the value like this:

```
<effects:HighPass InputSize="512.0,256.0"/>
```

it works.

Comment: You could create a Property where its' `get` returns the values in the correct type.

Comment: HighPass is my custom HLSL shader. InputSize is a float2 property. I updated my post. Directly passing in 512.0, 256.0 works as expected. I assume my syntax is incorrect when binding.

Comment: What I'm saying is you're trying to bind 2 properties to one thing. What's stopping you from creating a property that's something like this `get { return new float2(Width, Height); }` (pseudocode) for example and then binding to that property?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```
<effects:HighPass>
       <effects:HighPass.InputSize Width="{Binding Width}" Height={Binding Height} />
 </effects:HighPass>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This assumes that the target binding object has two property named Width and Height

Comment: I believe the above wont work since float2 probably doesn't have any properties rather than those two are anonymous internal property. Probably you can use  @rshepp provided solution. Or use converter to return float2 type.